# Lebesgue integral of cardinal

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

What is $
\int_{E} f d\mu
$ if $\mu = \mu_c$ the cardinal measure on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: The counting measure?

Comment: yes, $\mu $ is the counting measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** It suffices to understand what is $\int_{\{n\}}fd\mu$ for each $n$.

Comment: So $\int_{\{n\}}fd\mu = f(n)$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Then $\int_E fd\mu = \sum\limits_{n,n\in E} f(n)$ ?

Comment: That is also correct, although you can just write it as $\sum\limits_{n\in E}f(n)$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to this stuff :)